# PHPMailer Throws Cryptic Exception On Windows

Tags: php, windows, phpmailer

I have the following code snippet in my php script:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);               
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->UserName = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'XXX';
$mail->Subject = 'TEST';        
$mail->MsgHTML($msg);       
$mail->AddAddress('test@gmail.com','Test User');
$mail->SetFrom("sitemanager@mysite.com","My User");
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

The $mail->Send() method never finishes executing so no error is returned but debugging with php I get the following in my browser debugging console:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Could not instantiate mail function.' in ...\data\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php:779
Stack trace:
#0 ...\data\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(662): PHPMailer-&gt;MailSend('Date: Fri, 4 Ap...', '--b1_50a0740efb...')
#1 ...\data\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(588): PHPMailer-&gt;PostSend()
#2 ...\data\utils.php(255): PHPMailer-&gt;Send()
#3 ...\data\utils.php(164): emailUploadNotification('ce219bf6-7188-1...', Array, 'ce219bf6-7188-1...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in <b>...\data\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php</b> on line <b>779</b><br />
```

I need some help finding out why I cannot send emails from my php script.  Thank you.

Comment: The only thing I notice (without having more knowledge about the line numbers): `$mail->AddAddress(test@gmail.com,'Test User');`. The mail address should certainly be surrounded by `"`, as it is a string.

Comment: You are correct.  It was a variable in my script and I just didn't place the quotes around it when I redacted it.